Correctly handle DONE for Server Sent Event with spring webflux client
I try to use the spring webflux client to call a rest API that returns Server-Sent-Event (chatgpt).
Here is my client :
public interface OpenAIAsyncClient {

  @PostExchange(url = "/chat/completions", accept = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  Flux<ChatCompletionResult> request(@RequestBody AbstractChatCompletionRequest request);
}


So I will receive a list of json object like this :
{"id":"chatcmpl-id","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1732310107,"model":"gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18","system_fingerprint":"fp","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"role":"assistant","content":"","refusal":null},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}
...
{"id":"chatcmpl-id","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1732310107,"model":"gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18","system_fingerprint":"fp","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"stop"}]}
[DONE]

But the last line is a [DONE] string that breaks jackson deserialization.
Is there a way to handle this correctly with the spring webflux client ?

Is the string [DONE] not  return by  yourself?  i mean  the  server side is all in your control ,so  you can filter it  in  SSE .

@Peng : the server side is Chatgpt, the client side is spring app.

Ok, the way I did It is to override a Jackson2JsonDecoder :
public class IgnoreDoneJackson2JsonDecoder extends Jackson2JsonDecoder {

  public IgnoreDoneJackson2JsonDecoder() {
    super();
  }

  public IgnoreDoneJackson2JsonDecoder(ObjectMapper mapper, MimeType... mimeTypes) {
    super(mapper, mimeTypes);
  }

  @Override
  public Object decode(DataBuffer buffer, @NotNull ResolvableType targetType, MimeType mimeType,
      Map<String, Object> hints) throws DecodingException {
    if (buffer.capacity() > 5) {
      var begin = buffer.toString(0, 6, Charset.defaultCharset());
      if ("[DONE]".equals(begin)) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return super.decode(buffer, targetType, mimeType, hints);
  }
}

And set it when creating the weclient :
var webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl(url)
    .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().serverSentEventDecoder(customDecoder))
    .build();

